# Vocabulary do not work on collective.z3cform.datagridfield's sub object schema because of the context is NO_VALUE

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I'm working on a content type that uses datagridfield.
Within the subobject, I have a choice field with a custom vocabulary.

The vocabulary work outside the datagrid (If I use it directly in the content type's schema). But when I add it to the subobject, it doesn't work anymore.

Looking at the debug note, I see the vocabluary's context is NO_VALUE.

Any hint/direction to make this works ?

This is the simplest schema that won't work (I think):

```
# Import 
from zope import schema
from zope.interface import Interface

from plone.directives import form
from collective.z3cform.datagridfield import DataGridFieldFactory, DictRow

# The container
class IMenu(Interface):
    dishes = schema.List(value_type=schema.TextLine())

# The vocabulary 
@grok.provider(IContextSourceBinder)
def getDishes(context):
    terms = [SimpleVocabulary.createTerm(dish, dish, dish) for dish in context.dishes]
    return SimpleVocabulary(terms)

# The object line
class IOrderLine(Interface):
    dish = schema.Choice(source=getDishes)
    quantity = schema.Int()

# The object
class IOrder(Interface):
    form.widget(dishes=DataGridFieldFactory)
    dishes = schema.List(value_type=DictRow(schema=IOrderLine))
```

Now I register Menu, Order as dexterity content type, add a menu and tried to add an order within it, I got an error on Order add view and this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module Products.PDBDebugMode.runcall, line 70, in pdb_runcall
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 66, in __call__
  Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 50, in update
  Module plone.dexterity.browser.add, line 112, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.fieldsets.extensible, line 59, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.patch, line 30, in GroupForm_update
  Module z3c.form.group, line 128, in update
  Module z3c.form.form, line 134, in updateWidgets
  Module z3c.form.field, line 277, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.multi, line 63, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.widget, line 171, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 477, in update
  Module collective.z3cform.datagridfield.datagridfield, line 107, in updateWidgets
  Module collective.z3cform.datagridfield.datagridfield, line 91, in getWidget
  Module z3c.form.browser.widget, line 171, in update
  Module z3c.form.object, line 217, in update
  Module z3c.form.object, line 208, in updateWidgets
  Module z3c.form.object, line 87, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.patch, line 21, in BaseForm_update
  Module z3c.form.form, line 150, in update
  Module z3c.form.form, line 134, in updateWidgets
  Module z3c.form.field, line 277, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.select, line 51, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.widget, line 171, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 220, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 214, in updateTerms
  Module zope.component._api, line 107, in getMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component._api, line 120, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component.registry, line 238, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 532, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module z3c.form.term, line 96, in ChoiceTerms
  Module zope.schema._field, line 349, in bind
  Module waga.game.core.content.interfaces, line 202, in getDishes
AttributeError: 'NO_VALUE' object has no attribute 'dishes'
> /home/quyetnd/Projects/waga.game.core/src/waga/game/core/content/interfaces.py(202)getDishes()
-> terms = [SimpleVocabulary.createTerm(dish, dish, dish) for dish in context.dishes]
```

The context object is an  instance.

Comment: Please provide your zope.schema and the error/debug trace, so people can help you.

Comment: I've update with a simple illustration and traceback

Answer (score 3):

This is limitation in `z3c.form` (at least some versions, I think it has been fixed in the newer ones).

My ugly workaround in vocab source function:

```
 if not context:
      context = getSite()
      if not context:
           # Form is rendered from console without HTTP request traversing, etc.
           # and thread local site variable is not set
           raise RuntimeError("Oh snap. Beer time.")

 ...
```

http://developer.plone.org/serving/traversing.html#using-getsite

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mikko :)
I also did that to by pass the problem in my vocabulary.
There's a Plone-intergrated version of subform adapter in plone.app.z3cform give us something more interesting other than NO_VALUE, but still not intelligent enough in my case (not the plone's context).

A side note is that because of plone.app.z3cform exists, the DatagridFieldSubform adapter will never be looked up. Zope got plone.app.z3cform version instead, which is currently not autoform-aware. I needed to re-register the factory to make it works.